# Scala: how to append to a Seq

Tags: scala, append, seq

I am struggling with the following piece of code:

```
type DB = Map[Int, Seq[String]]
var grades: DB = Map.empty
def add(name: String, grade: Int) = {
  var names: Seq[String] = Seq(name)
  if(grades isDefinedAt grade) {
    names = names ++ grades(grade)
  }
    grades += (grade -> names)
}
```

When I call the "add" method, as follow:

```
add(2, "Mike")
add(2, "Michelle")
add(2, "John")
```

I would expect `grades` to be `(2, Seq(Mike, Michelle, John))` but, instead, it contains only the last addition `(2, John)`.

How can I solve that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Also, your add method is (String, Int) whereas you are calling it by add(Int, String)

    scala> add("Mike", 2)

    scala> grades
    res2: DB = Map(2 -> List(Mike))

    scala> add("Michelle", 2)
    scala> grades
    res4: DB = Map(2 -> List(Michelle, Mike))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do the same in more Scala way (no side effects, pure functional), take a look to this:

```
type DB = Map[Int, Seq[String]]

def add(db: DB, name: String, grade: Int): DB = {
  db.get(grade) match {
    case Some(seq) => // key exists, let's update the value
      val newSeq = seq :+ name  // create new sequence
      db.updated(grade, newSeq)
    case None =>      // key does not exist, let's add new key
      db + (grade -> Seq(name))
  }
}

val db: DB = Map.empty

val db1 = add(db, name = "A", grade = 1)
println(s"db1: $db1")

val db2 = add(db1, name = "B", grade = 1)
println(s"db2: $db2")

val db3 = add(db2, name = "C", grade = 2)
println(s"db3: $db3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Only thing I'd mention is that `add` expects `Int, String`, where you're calling it as `add(2, "Mike")` (ie `Int, String`) - this won't compile. Here's the output of my Scala console (after flipping the order of the input variables when calling your `add` method):

```
scala> type DB = Map[Int, Seq[String]]
defined type alias DB

scala> var grades: DB = Map.empty
grades: DB = Map()

scala> def add(name: String, grade: Int) = {
     |   var names: Seq[String] = Seq(name)
     |   if(grades isDefinedAt grade) {
     |     names = names ++ grades(grade)
     |   }
     |   grades += (grade -> names)
     | }
add: (grade: Int, name: String)Unit

scala> 

scala> add("Mike", 2)

scala> add("Michelle", 2)

scala> add("John", 2)

scala> grades
res3: DB = Map(2 -> List(John, Michelle, Mike))
```

I'm not sure why it didn't work for you. If you had got the first two inputs the wrong way around like I initially thought, ie `add(2, "Mike")` etc, you would expect the output to be `(2, List(John))` and not just `(2, John)`. I think you broke the laws of Scala there.

Just as a "best practice" thing, it would be better to avoid `var` where possible. This could be rewritten without mutable variables. There's a good article by [alvinalexander](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-idiom-immutable-code-functional-programming-immutability) which explains the preference for immutable variables. Worth a read.